Azure B2C Custom Policy - Modify Sign-in inputs
Hi Im just starting to user custom policy for Azure B2C.
I would want to create a signin/signup page where I have a customized input in sign in based from combined signup data.
Example:
In Signup the following will be asked from the user:

Department name
User Id
Password
**combination of #1 and #2 must be unique, but individually they can be not unique.

In Sigin

Username will be (<departmentName_userId>)
Password
or if its easier it can be 3 inputs
Dept name
User Id
Password
When user sign in, i have to validate those 3 items.

Are there any good reference for this? Ive been trying to modify the starter pack for LocalAccount custom policy from Microsoft but could not make the behavior like this?
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack
Thank you!
